Devise sign out does not work in after_sign_in_path_for
I am trying this approach with Devise to force a password reset on the first login. Redirection works, but the password is not reset as the user is not signed out... Seemingly sign_out is not working here. How can I force Devise to sign out?
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    unless request.path == edit_user_password_path(resource)
      if current_user.sign_in_count == 1 && !current_user.reset_password_token.present?
        raw, hashed = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
        current_user.reset_password_token = hashed
        current_user.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
        current_user.save
        sign_out current_user
        edit_user_password_path(current_user, reset_password_token: raw)
      else
        root_path
      end
    end
  end
end


Why do you want to force a password reset? Seems annoying. Devise has a built in Confirmable module if that's what you're trying to acheive.
